# How to set default locale for a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to set a default locale of controller in Rails. Suppose the application supports different language like, fr, nl, en, cn etc and I want to use 'en' as a default language for the Admin Dashboard Controller. Please suggest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a `before_action` callback to set the default locale.

```
class Admin::DashboardController
  before_action :set_default_locale

  # ...

  private
    def set_default_locale
      I18n.default_locale = :en
    end
end
```

Comment: When i sign in to Admin Dashboard default locale doesn't set to :en

Comment: Well did you add this code to the correct controller?

Comment: Have you tried using a log statement or any other debugging methods to check that set_default_locale is actually being run?

Answer (score 3):

```
before_action :set_locale
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

more details  in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164970/locale-not-set-in-application-controller) and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: I have set locale locale rule in application.rb but I want to set :en as default locale for a DashboardController